# What do Collections class references EMPTY_LIST, EMPTY_SET and EMPTY_MAP point to?

Tags: java, collections

This is a follow-up question to one I asked earlier. The Collections class has three final interface references, EMPTY_LIST, EMPTY_SET and EMPTY_MAP. What do they point to? For example, does the reference EMPTY_LIST point to an instantiated object of the LIST type with no elements? If so, what is the concrete class of this object?

Comment: The source code comes with the JDK. Why don't you look at it?

Comment: Read the javadoc. Use `getClass()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concrete classes of those objects are hard-coded direct implementations of an empty collection; they aren't publicly visible or used anywhere else.  See e.g. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.0EMPTY_LIST.

Answer (score 1):

**For example, does the reference EMPTY_LIST point to an instantiated object of the LIST type with no elements?**

Yes

**If so, what is the concrete class of this object?**

Who cares.  `List` `Set` and `Map` are interfaces.  As long as the class implements the interface it doesn't matter what the class is called.

Also, it is better not to use the `EMPTY_LIST`, `EMPTY_SET`, and `EMPTY_MAP`fields directly since they don't use generics.  It is better instead of use the related static methods (ex: `Collections.emptyMap()`) which use type inferencng to guess the generic types.

This will work

```
Map<String, Foo> empty = Collections.emptyMap();
```

This will throw a type safety warning

```
Map<String, Foo> empty = Collections.EMPTY_MAP;
```

Answer (score 1):

For information you can get the answer by yourself by reading the source code of java :
(it's the file src.zip in your JDK folder)

So

```
public static final List EMPTY_LIST = new EmptyList<>();
```

with this definition :

```
private static class EmptyList<E>
        extends AbstractList<E>
        implements RandomAccess, Serializable {
```